# DFS a tree with no memory

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to write a function to traverse a tree with depth first search.

My current algorithm goes something like:

```
If children
 go to first child

If no children
 go to next sibling

If no siblings
 go to parent
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can't mark nodes on the tree as having been visited, so when I go to the parent the cycle just resets and it goes to the child again, getting stuck in a loop. Does anyone have any idea as to how I could solve this?

(It's in java using the ANTLR plugin)

EDIT:

Following one of the suggestions I wrote this:

```
public void traverseTree(Tree tree){

    if (tree.getChildCount() > 0){
        tree = tree.getChild(0);
        traverseTree(tree);
        System.out.println(tree.toString());
    }
    if (tree.getParent().getChild(tree.getChildIndex() + 1) != null){
        tree = tree.getParent().getChild(tree.getChildIndex() + 1);
        traverseTree(tree);
        System.out.println(tree.toString());
    }
    if (!tree.getParent().toString().contains("ROOT_NODE")){
        tree = tree.getParent();
        traverseTree(tree);
        System.out.println(tree.toString());
    }
}
```

Root node is the name of the root node, but I'm getting a stack overflow error. Anyone have any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need to worry about cycles or some such then the simplest approach is to use a recursive approach as @PeterLawrey suggests.  Clean and simple.  If you can't use recursion you can still use a separate stack to maintain the same info, including the linked list of where to return to, if the nodes are not back-linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use recursion in this case.

```
class Node {
   public List<Node> getChildren() { .... }

   public void traverse(Visitor<Node> visitor) {
      // If children
      // go to first child - by traversing the children first.
       for(Node kid: getChildren())
           kid.traverse(visitor);
           // If no children
           //  go to next sibling, - by continuing the loop.

       visitor.visit(this);
       // If no siblings
       // go to parent - by returning and letting the parent be processed
   }
}


interface Vistor<N> {
   public void visit(N n);
}
```

Comment: That looks nice, I'm not sure I 100% understand it though. Could you explain what it's doing exactly? (Sorry, I'm pretty bad at just reading code).

Comment: I have added comments.  You might find it useful to step through the code in a debugger to see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried writing it out in a java file to understand it, but I'm having trouble getting it to run, it doesn't recognise Visitor or getChildren() (Although I think for that I just need to change to the weird ANTLR format).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it. I've updated the main post with code I wrote for it (to make it work in ANTLR). But I'm getting a stack overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

Using a hash_table map each vertex to boolean indicate whether visited or not

Comment: In a tree search, this should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Write a depth first Iterator that keeps track of visited nodes internally.  That way the tree doesn't have to change to know that it's being watched.

Answer (score 0):

If "no memory" can be interpreted as O(1) memory, then the change may help:

1. Remember not only the current node, but also node where you came from
2. Traverse children only if you didn't came from one of them